# How to get URL of active tab in browser in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, url, ui-automation, freeze

I'm in the process of coding an application to **capture URL of active tab** in Chrome browser. I went through some of codes and all those codes cause the GUI freeze and take a long time to get the URL. What I realy want is to get the URL of active tab. That's all .This is what I have used. Highly appreciate your help.

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation

Public Class Form1
    Private Const ChromeProcess As [String] = "chrome"
    Private Const AddressCtl As [String] = "Address and search bar"
Public Function GetChromeActiveWindowUrl() As [String]
    Dim procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(ChromeProcess)

    If (procs.Length = 0) Then
        Return [String].Empty
    End If

    Return procs _
.Where(Function(p) p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero) _
.Select(Function(s) GetUrlControl(s)) _
.Where(Function(p) p IsNot Nothing) _
.Select(Function(s) GetValuePattern(s)) _
.Where(Function(p) p.Item2.Length > 0) _
.Select(Function(s) GetValuePatternUrl(s)) _
.FirstOrDefault

End Function

Private Function GetUrlControl(
proses As Process) _
As AutomationElement

    Dim propCondition =
    New PropertyCondition(
    AutomationElement.NameProperty,
    AddressCtl)
    Return AutomationElement _
    .FromHandle(proses.MainWindowHandle) _
    .FindFirst(
        TreeScope.Descendants,
        propCondition)

End Function

Private Function GetValuePatternUrl(
element As Tuple(Of
AutomationElement, AutomationPattern())) As [String]

    Dim ap = element.Item2(0)
    Dim ovp = element.Item1.GetCurrentPattern(ap)
    Dim vp = CType(ovp, ValuePattern)

    Return vp.Current.Value
End Function



Private Function GetValuePattern(
element As AutomationElement) _
```

As Tuple(Of
          AutomationElement,
          AutomationPattern())

```
      Return New Tuple(Of
      AutomationElement,
      AutomationPattern())(
      element,
      element.GetSupportedPatterns())
End Function
```

Comment: Is this for a browser plugin?

Comment: No for VB.Net application

Comment: If it's a web application, and not built into a browser. Or a browser extension, then you will not have access to a user's browsing session for security reasons. So getting info on what tabs a user has open, or which one is active would be off-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the answer to my Question,

I have blocked the requests receiving from other applications and focused only on the chrome browser

```
Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
Dim ProcessID As UInt32 = Nothing
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ProcessID)
Dim Proc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessID)
str_application_category = Proc.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName

If str_application_category = "Google Chrome" Then
str_application_path = GetChromeActiveWindowUrl()
End If

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```